# Python detection of delimiter/separator in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, separator

I have a function that reads and handles `*.csv` files in several dataframes.

However, not all of the CSV files have the same separator. So, how could python can detect which type of separator does the csv file has, and then used it in `read_csv()` function to read it in pandas?

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = 'xxx',header = None, index_col = 0)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

In fact, use `engine='python'` as parameter of `read_csv`. It will try to automatically detect the right delimiter.

> **sepstr, default ‘,’**
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.

Use [`csv.Sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer):

```
import csv

def find_delimiter(filename):
    sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
    with open(filename) as fp:
        delimiter = sniffer.sniff(fp.read(5000)).delimiter
    return delimiter
```

Demo:

```
>>> find_delimiter('data.csv')
','

>>> find_delimiter('data.txt')
' '
```

Comment: Is there a reason for 5000 value inside fp.read()?

Comment: Just a maximum buffer size to avoid reading the whole file. I think 5000 bytes is sufficient to determine the separator.

Comment: Wow! It works !!! I saw other posts where they iterate over a possible list of separators, but it is likely to get an error. However, with your answer, it works really well!!

Comment: Setting  `pandas.read_csv('data.csv',sep=None)` detects too the separator automatically and it also uses the python engine

Answer (score 4):

As Reda El Hail said in comments before, set the param `sep = None`, like this:

```
pandas.read_csv('data.csv',sep=None)
```

And if you use the lib awswrangler to read csv files in s3, you can do similar to this:

```
awswrangler.s3.read_csv('s3://bucket/prefix', sep = None)
```